# Examples of Categories that are not Complete

Tags: category-theory

I have been studying Category Theory and I am now trying to become more familiar with the definition of complete categories. I understand the definition well, but I was hoping to develop some sort of intuition to predict when a category may be complete or not. I think looking at counter-examples may be helpful, but I have not been able to find many.

Taking the definition: A category is complete if it has all small limits. I know that many familiar categories are complete, such as **Ab**, **Set** and **Top**. Are there examples of familiar categories that are not complete? If there aren't examples of "familiar" categories that are not complete, what are some examples of "unfamiliar" ones?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_category) gives several examples and non-examples (like the category of wheels :) =.

Comment: It's worth mentioning the category of smooth manifolds as well, which is far from either complete or cocomplete (e.g. non-transverse intersections).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a whole class of examples obtained by deliberately destroying an otherwise perfectly complete category. For instance, take the complete category $\mathbf {Set}$ of sets and functions. Now, remove from it all sets with precisely $4$ distinct elements. You still have a category but now there is no product of any two doubleton sets.

Other examples are infinite lattices that are not complete lattices. Any lattice is a special category (one where hom sets are sub-singletons). In a lattice you have all finite joins and meets, and these are, respectively, coproducts and products. All other finite colimits and limits exist automatically. However, not all lattices are complete, namely they need not have all meets. In other words, any lattice that is not complete is a category that if finitely complete but not complete. Of course, there are many many posets that do not even have finite products.

Then there are examples coming from algebra. For instance, every field has a characteristic and the characteristic is preserved by the morphisms (this is a very strong property that is quite unique to fields). Consequently, the product of two fields of different characteristics cannot exist.

And finally you can form non-complete categories by forcing them not to be sufficiently large, in a sense. For example, the category of all finite sets has all finite limits but not all infinite products.

Answer (score 1):

The category of fields fails awfully in this regard: if $K$ and $L$ are fields of different characteristics, there are *no* maps $K \to L$. Hence we cannot form a (co)product between $K$ and $L$ in $\mathsf{Field}$.